# Strange behaviour on method annotations and default access level

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Here's my problem...

I have an annotation in package pkg3:

```
package pkg3;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TestAnno {

}
```

Also I have two classes in package pkg1, one with public access and one with default access

```
package pkg1;

import pkg3.TestAnno;

class Class1 {

    @TestAnno
    public void test1() { }

    public void test2() { }

}
```

and

```
package pkg1;

import pkg3.TestAnno;

public class Class2 extends Class1 {

    @TestAnno
    public void test3() { }

    public void test4() { }

}
```

Finnally I've got a main class in package pkg2

```
package pkg2;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import pkg1.Class2;
import pkg3.TestAnno;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Class2 cls = new Class2();
        for(Method m: cls.getClass().getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(m);
            if (m.getAnnotation(TestAnno.class) != null) {
                System.out.println("  > hass anno");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Running this example I expect to see the info, that two methods have @TestAnno present - test1 and test3, but I only see one test3, and... what is strange, the methods test1 and test2 are listed as they were be declared in class Class2.

```
public void pkg1.Class2.test3()
  > hass anno
public void pkg1.Class2.test4()
public void pkg1.Class2.test1()
public void pkg1.Class2.test2()
public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException
... rest methods from java.lang.Object
```

I know, that getMethods returns only public methods from given glass (and it's all super classes) but... this is strange for me.

I'm using this in order to separate generated classes (which have default access) from implementation classes (which are public and they're extending generated classes).
Have I to use public access in generated classes (I wanted them not to be visible to rest of the world) or is there any way to get annotated public methods from Class1 ?

Comment: That's the official behavior https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029563, but it's a strange strategy.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just a "one big maybe" made by a man at 3 a.m. so it will require JLS confrontation, better terminology and more informations. I was planning to post it as comment but unfortunately it is too long :/

---

Lets take a look at this classes

```
class SomeClass {
    @TestAnno
    public void test(){}
}

class SomeDefaultClass extends SomeClass {
}

public class SomePublicClass extends SomeClass {
}
```

now take a look at this code and its result

```
Method m1 = SomePublicClass.class.getMethod("test");
Method m2 = SomeDefaultClass.class.getMethod("test");

System.out.println(m1 + "\t> " + m1.getAnnotation(TestAnno.class));
System.out.println(m2 + "\t\t> " + m2.getAnnotation(TestAnno.class));
```

output

```
public void SomePublicClass.test()  > null
public void SomeClass.test()        > @TestAnno()
```

As you see public class that extends class with package modifier doesn't inherit annotations, but class with package modifier does.

---

Why is that?
Both `SomeDefaultClass` and `SomePublicClass` "inherited" `test()` method but not in the same way.

If you take a look at result of `javap SomeDefaultClass.class` you will see

```
class SomeDefaultClass extends SomeClass {
  SomeDefaultClass();
}
```

so it doesn't have `test()` method in its binaries, so it will use it from `SomeClass` which have `TestAnno` annotation.

On the other hand if you take a look at result of `javap SomePublicClass` you will see

```
public class SomePublicClass extends SomeClass {
  public SomePublicClass();
  public void test();
}
```

which means that code of `test()` method has been overridden in `SomePublicClass` so this method has been declared again in `SomePublicClass` but ***unfortunately without previous annotations*** and since overridden method doesn't have annotations you wont see them in your code. (Why annotations are not added when compiler is overriding method? Honestly, I don't know :/)

Why is overriding happening? I suspect that since `SomePublicClass` is ***public*** and `test` is also ***public*** it should be accessible from all packages, but since `SomeClass` has **default/package** visibility this method couldn't be accessible via `SomeClass` from outside of its package.

---

To prevent moving/copying `test` method from one class to another you can make both classes `public` or `default/package`.